# D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC: Element types / ordering / packing

Tags: c++, data-structures, direct3d11

Are there concerns (performance or other) related to the types / ordering of elements in a D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC structure? For example, I now have an input layout defined like this:

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC QuadInputLayoutDescription[] = {
    { "PRECT",  0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,  0, 0,                               D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 },
    { "DEPTH",  0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT,           0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,    D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 },
    { "TEXID",  0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT,            0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,    D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 },
    { "SLICE",  0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT,           0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,    D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 },
    { "UVRCT",  0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,  0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,    D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 },
    { "COLOR",  0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,  0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT,    D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 } };
```

Does it matter that the `TEXID` element is of type `UINT` rather than `FLOAT` here? Is "alignment" against a four component vector struct (float4) preferred; Should I "pack" all the `R32G32B32A32_FLOAT`s together at the beginning of the layout? Is anything padded?

Comment: UINT is ok on 10_0+ feature sets but it's recommended to specify your own offsets, otherwise you need to read all the docs regarding packing rules. I'd assume that UVRCT has an offset of 32 due to a float4 alignment rule.

Answer (score 1):

The primary performance issue for input layouts is the total size of them as it directly impacts the amount of data that has to pass through the pre- and post-transform vertex cache. Historically, the idea total size is 32 bytes or 64 bytes.

Otherwise, the types you use don't usually make a lot of difference in terms of performance. The limit on types used is your target hardware [Feature Level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx).